# split string with multiple delimeters in SAS

Tags: sas

How to split the below string (multiple delimeters) into seperate columns in SAS?

> [INTERCEPT]-2[/INTERCEPT] [COUNTRY]MY[/COUNTRY]
>   [LOG_AMT]0.2354[/LOG_AMT] [BETAX]-11.08325[/BETAX]

```
> INTERCEPT  COUNTRY   LOG_AMT     BETAX
> -2           MY       0.2354    -11.08325
```

Comment: You are more likely to get a helpful answer if you put a little more effort into your question, especially showing code that you have tried so far, or research that you have done.

Comment: If your file is originally a JSON, XML, or HTML data it would help to indicate that, there are other methods to read such a file.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way of doing this would be generate a key value pair by reading using @@ and delimiter as '['. After key value pair is generated using proc transpose you can generate the exact same result. This way if in future something more is property-value pair are added the code would still be able to generate the result perfectly. Check the out the below code.

```
data have;
length key value $ 20.;
retain key ' ';
retain group 1;
infile datalines dlm=']' ;
    input text :$char20. @@;
    key=lag(text);
    if find(text,'[/') then do;
        key=scan(key,2,'[','mo');
        value=scan(text,1,'[');
        output;
    end;
    drop text;
datalines;
[INTERCEPT]-2[/INTERCEPT] [COUNTRY]MY[/COUNTRY] [LOG_AMT]0.2354[/LOG_AMT] [BETAX]-11.08325[/BETAX]
;;;;
run;
proc transpose data=have out=want(drop=group _name_);
    by group;
    var value;
    id key;
    idlabel key;
run;
proc print data=want;run;
```

Personally, I prefer using sas perl regular expression for breaking  properties/value in key value pair. You could look into as well for breaking properties/value into key value pair.