# How to split columns based on a delimiter?

Tags: sas, delimiter

My dataset has the following columns

```
Mileage        Engine
19.23 km/l     1300 CC
```

there are more than 8000 rows.

I want to split these columns based on the space between the values to show the below result

```
Mileage 1  Mileage 2  Engine 1  Engine 2
19.23      km/l       1300      CC
```

Both columns have character data type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [split string with multiple delimeters in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427905/split-string-with-multiple-delimeters-in-sas)

Comment: Do you want `Mileage1` and `Engine1` to be numeric variables ?  Do any of the original values NOT conform to the <number><space><unit> construct ?

Answer (score 1):

In SAS you can split a value using the `SCAN` function to extract parts of a delimited string.  The `INPUT` function converts a numeric representation in a string to a numeric value.

```
* ICE ICE baby;
mpg      = input (scan(mileage,1), best12.);
mpg_unit =        scan(mileage,2);
eng_size = input (scan(engine, 1), best12.);
eng_unit =        scan(engine, 2);
```